# c# get info from query that existed or was created

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var sysExist = db.Systems.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == name && 
s.OrganizationID == 4);

if (sysExist == null)
{
   var sys = db.Systems.Add(new Systems()
   {
      Name = name,
      OrganizationID = 4,
      Online = true,
      SerialNumber = "1zz34343" 
   });

   db.Systems.Add(sys);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the record existed, I need to get the ID field from sysExist. If record did not exist, I need to get the ID field of the record that was added (sys). Wondering there is a more efficient way to do this vs. looking at both vars to see what the ID was.

Comment: Why are you calling `db.Systems.Add` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reuse `sysExist` instead of creating a new `sys`:

```
var sysExist = db.Systems.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == name && s.OrganizationID == 4);

if (sysExist  == null)
{
   sysExist = new Systems()
   {
     Name = name,
     OrganizationID = 4,
     Online = true,
     SerialNumber = "1zz34343" 
   };

   db.Systems.Add(sysExist);
   db.SaveChanges();
}

// now sysExist contains old or new record
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sys = db.Systems.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == name && 
s.OrganizationID == 4);

if (sys  == null)
{
   sys = new Systems()
   {
     Name = name,
     OrganizationID = 4,
     Online = true,
     SerialNumber = "1zz34343" 
   };

   db.Systems.Add(sys);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Then use `sys` where you need to get the ID

Comment: Code only answers are not usually helpful.  Why does your answer solve the OP's problem?

Comment: "Wondering there is a more efficient way to do this vs. looking at both vars to see what the ID was" I believe my change was a response to this